# FirebaseStorage Can't Store Drawings properly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-image, android-bitmap

In my project I make an bitmap from an custom view which is a drawing. I can't upload many drawings at once, because they get overwritten. After that, I get the URI of the Bitmap and upload the drawing to FirebaseStorage. I get an error that says: Invalid request. X-Goog-Upload-Command header is missing. Also, when I go to the download URL from FirebaseStorage were the drawing is stored, I get this error:

```
{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
}
}
```

Here is my code:

```
public class SharedClass extends AppCompatActivity {

StorageReference firebaseStorage;

DatabaseReference databaseReference;

FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
FirebaseUser currentUser;
String uID;

String imgFileName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);


}

public void uploadImageToStorage(final Context context, Uri imageURI, String chosenTopic, String typeOfImage) {

   // Toast.makeText(context, "Context: " + context, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   // Toast.makeText(context, "Image URI: " + imageURI, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   // Toast.makeText(context, "chosen topic : " + chosenTopic, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   // Toast.makeText(context, "Type of image: " + typeOfImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth.getInstance();

    currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    uID = currentUser.getUid().toString();

    //Toast.makeText(context, "uID: " + uID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child(uID)
            .child("sak_1")
            .child(chosenTopic)
            .child("images");

    firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    StorageReference filepath = firebaseStorage.child(uID).child(typeOfImage + String.valueOf(imageURI.getLastPathSegment()));

    filepath.putFile(imageURI).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Laddade upp bild", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Uri imageDownloadURL = taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri();

            //Call uploadImageToDatabase with taskSnapshot.getDowloadURI
            uploadImageToDatabase(imageDownloadURL);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Bilden laddades inte upp", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.i("AppInfo", String.valueOf(e.getCause()));
        }
    });
}

public class DrawingFragment extends Fragment {

Button newDrawingButton;

StorageReference drawingsRef;

FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
FirebaseUser currentUser;
String uID;

public DrawingFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drawing, container, false);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    uID = currentUser.getUid().toString();

    drawingsRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
            .child(uID);

    newDrawingButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.new_drawing_button);

    newDrawingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            newDrawing();
        }
    });

    return v;
}

public void newDrawing() {

    final AlertDialog.Builder drawingDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    final CustomDrawer customDrawer = new CustomDrawer(getContext(), null, 5f);
    customDrawer.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    customDrawer.buildDrawingCache();
    customDrawer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    drawingDialogBuilder.setView(customDrawer);


    drawingDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton("Spara", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            doneWithDrawing(customDrawer);

            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog drawDialog = drawingDialogBuilder.create();

    drawDialog.getWindow().setLayout(500, 500);

    drawDialog.show();
}

public void doneWithDrawing(View drawedView) {

    Bitmap drawedImageBitmap = drawedView.getDrawingCache();

    //The byte array that the stream is written into.
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    //compress the bitmap into the stream.
    drawedImageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

    //data contains the bytes of the compressed bitmap
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

    //Upload the task so that we can get the download uri.
    UploadTask uploadTask = drawingsRef.putBytes(data);

    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            Uri drawedImageUri = taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri();

            uploadDrawing(drawedImageUri);
        }
    });
}

public void uploadDrawing(Uri uri) {

    String typeOfImage = String.valueOf("dawing");

    SharedClass sharedClass = new SharedClass();
    sharedClass.uploadImageToStorage(getActivity(), uri, getArguments().getString("chosenTopic"), typeOfImage);
}
}

public class CustomDrawer extends View {

Paint paint;

Path path;

public CustomDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, float paintWidth) {
    super(context, attributeSet);

    paint = new Paint();

    path = new Path();

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(paintWidth);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    float xPos = event.getX();
    float yPos = event.getY();

    //What kind of event were there?
    switch (event.getAction()) {

        //Started to draw
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            path.moveTo(xPos, yPos);

            break;

        //Moved the finger
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            path.lineTo(xPos, yPos);

            break;

        //Released finger
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;
    }

    invalidate();

    return true;
}
}
```

The drawing in storage

[image]